# How to bypass java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException?

Tags: java, file, nio

Is there a way to bypass a `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`? I want to be able to delete a folder with content in it.

Comment: I think you need to delete the contents, then delete the directory.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This question is asking if you can delete a directory *without* doing all of that.

Comment: @StephenC:  [After looking at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) and the suggested duplicate, I'm more inclined to think it *is* a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to bypass a `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`?

No.  There is no way to bypass it.

On Linux / Unix, the restriction is ultimately imposed by the operating system.  See [`man 2 rmdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rmdir), and the `ENOTEMPTY` error code.

Also, try running [`rmdir`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rmdir) from the command prompt on a non-empty directory, and see what happens.

---

As other comments state, you need to empty the directory first.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot bypass it. You have to delete the files and sub-directories first in the folder. There are many examples available on the web for how to do this.