# java delete directory in windows

Tags: java, windows

I try to delete a directory using java,here is my code

```
 public static void delDirectory(String path) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    delHelp(p);
}

private static void delHelp(Path p) throws IOException {
    if (!p.toFile().exists()) {
        return;
    } else if(p.toFile().isFile()){
        log.debug("delete file:" + p.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        Files.delete(p);
    }else if(p.toFile().isDirectory()){
        for(Path subPath:Files.newDirectoryStream(p)){
            delHelp(subPath);
        }
        log.debug("delete directory:"+p.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        Files.delete(p);
    }
}
```

On unix-like system, it works out. On windows, the code `Files.delete(p)` actually move the directory to the trash can, so when delete the parent directory the code will throw exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`

Any idea about this os-dependent behavior? How can I work around this?

Comment: It sounds so strange. As far as I know recycler bin works only when you use it with windows explorer. Which library are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is caused by the Trash Can? As far as I know (and reading at other posts) it could be possible just by deleting all subdirectories and files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872608/how-to-bypass-java-nio-file-directorynotemptyexception

Comment: Is it `java.nio.file.Files.delete()` and are you sure it moves the file to trash? On my system (Win7) it deletes it directly, and in general people seem to have the opposite problem regarding trash bin (i.e. making it work).

Comment: yes,I use import java.nio.file.Files to delete directory. And every thing works fine on my mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is that you are not closing the `DirectoryStream`, which is causing the `DirectoryNotEmptyException` when you try to delete the directory.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-):

> When not using the try-with-resources construct, then directory stream's close method should be invoked after iteration is completed so as to free any resources held for the open directory.

So you can either call `close()` on it when you are done with it, or use it in try-with-resources:

```
private static void delHelp(Path p) throws IOException {
    if (!p.toFile().exists()) {
        return;
    } else if(p.toFile().isFile()){
        Files.delete(p);
    } else if(p.toFile().isDirectory()){

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(p)) {
            for (Path subPath : ds){
                delHelp(subPath);
            }
        }

        Files.delete(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please first of all add this [Jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio14jar.htm) into your project first.

Find below code works perfectly as per your requirement too.

i.e. work on window machine and should be not goes to trash/recycle-bin

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                delDirectory("E:\\RecursiveDataContainDirectoryName");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public static void delDirectory(String path) throws IOException {
                Path p = Paths.get(path);
                FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(p.toFile());
        }
```

Comment: thanks, but I really want to know the native java library could do this work or not